# UIViewController disappears while loading a UIView

Tags: iphone

I have a presenetModalViewcontroller on which I add a viewcontroller. When I click a button on that viewcontroller I need to load a view. Right now I am a loading a transparent view on the before mentioned viewController. But as I load the view, my viewController behind it shows a blank view.Its as if the viewController has disappeared. I cannot find a solution to what is happening. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Sounds kinda strange to click a button on a viewcontroller. You should provide code snippets...

Comment: My mistake . I was referring to a toolbar button. On the click of this toolbar button, my view loads. The view is transparent and I can see a  my viewController behind it, but it is having a blank view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was loading the view in an incorrect manner.
This code worked

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"NewView" owner:self options:nil];
[self.newView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
[self.view addSubview:newView];
```

Answer (score 1):

Your new view more than likely has an opaque background. Set the UIView's 'opaque' property to 'NO' and its backgroundColor to [UIColor clearColor].

Comment: My view is having a transparent background. I have checked that. And even when I am removing the view, instead of my viewController appearing. I am getting a kind of blank view.